# Different architecture problem when loading saved model

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, data-science

Trained my model using:

```
history = model.fit(x=[train1,train2,train3,train4,train5,train6,train7,train8,train9],
          y=[y1,y2,y3,y4,y5,y6,y7,y8,y9], callbacks=callbacks,
          batch_size=100, epochs=1, verbose=1, validation_split=0.1, shuffle=False) #change batch to 10 for best results
```

Then I saved the weights+ architecture using:

```
model.save('my_model.h5')
```

I can load the model just fine using:

```
new_model_2 = load_model('my_model.h5')
```

But when I try to predict:

```
new_model_2.fit(x=[train1,train2,train3,train4,train5,train6,train7,train8,train9],
          y=[y1,y2,y3,y4,y5,y6,y7,y8,y9], callbacks=callbacks,
          batch_size=100, epochs=1, verbose=1, validation_split=0.1, shuffle=False)
```

I get the weirdest error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking model input: the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 8 array(s), but instead got the following list of 9 arrays: [array([[ 6.46234854e-27,  0.00000000e+00, -1.55096365e-24, ...,
```

I'm saying it's the weirdest, because when I print the model summary it shows similar architecture to my model.
Also, when I tried to remove y9 and train9 the error changed to:

```
new_model_2.fit(x=[train1,train2,train3,train4,train5,train6,train7,train8],
          y=[y1,y2,y3,y4,y5,y6,y7,y8], callbacks=callbacks,
          batch_size=100, epochs=1, verbose=1, validation_split=0.1, shuffle=False)

ValueError: Error when checking model target: the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 9 array(s), but instead got the following list of 8 arrays: [array([[-3.23117427e-27,  0.00000000e+00, -1.55096365e-24, ...,
```